# How set Images on center of button in android ?

Tags: android, button, layout

I wont to display the images on button Like this
[image]

but button is set :

[image]

I am writting code for that is

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/menu"
    android:gravity="center"  />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAction"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_anchor"
        android:gravity="center" 
         />  
    </LinearLayout>
```

Please help me to how to set this...

Comment: `android:layout_height="match_parent"` is creating that problem..Try hardcoding the height..

Comment: set height as wrapcontent for button and textview

Comment: You set image in button ?

Comment: I am trying this but it will not work

Answer (score 1):

Hard coding your dimensions is not a good perspective i think

### Try this code

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="5" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/menu"
android:gravity="center"  />

<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_anchor"
    android:gravity="center" 
     />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It got same as previous

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/menu"
        android:gravity="center"  />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAction"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_anchor"
        android:gravity="center" 
         />  
    </LinearLayout>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/menu"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_anchor"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `wrap_content` for height..

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/menu"
android:gravity="center"  />

<TextView

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_anchor"
    android:gravity="center" 
     />  
</LinearLayout>
```